# C# ComboBox to activate dropdown list when clicking on dropdown text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

I've got a Windows Forms application written in Visual Studio 2015. Its a simple form with a couple of dropdown menus (combo boxes) and I'm wanting the dropdown list to pull down when the user clicks anywhere in the combobox frame, not only when they click on the arrow right hand side.

[image]

The combobox in my code is as follows:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cbxMake;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution to be changing the DropDownStyle in the Appearance properties from `DropDown` to `DropdownList`

This did exactly what I was after - changing it from this

[image]

To this

[image]

Which enabled me to select the dropdown list by clicking anywhere in the box, rather than just on the arrow on the far right of the combobox.

Comment: @GrantWinney - correct, its a static dropdown list.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to allow the user to enter text in the TextBox portion of the ComboBox, but also display the drop-down list when the user clicks the TextBox, subscribe to the `MouseClick` event:

```
private void cbxMake_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    cbxMake.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

No matter where the user clicks on the control, whether it's the "down" triangle or the TextBox, the drop-down will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks Grant, I don't require user to input text outside the list items, but I'll keep this in mind for future use.